# Pandas data frame - apply function with lambda with multiple 'if else' statements

Tags: python, pandas

I am hoping someone could help point out what I may be doing wrong in the following piece of code:

```
master_output['tm_override'] = master_output.apply(lambda row: row['nrec_tm_lb'].astype(str) + '-' + row['nrec_tm_ub'].astype(str) if row['det_tw_fact'].isin([4, 5]) else row['tw2Open'] + dt.timedelta(hours=3).time() if (row['det_tw_fact'].isin([1, 2, 3]) and (~row['tw2Open'].isna()))
else row['tw1Open'] + dt.timedelta(hours=3).time() if (row['det_tw_fact'].isin([1, 2, 3]) and (~row['tw2Open'].isna())), axis=1)
```

I have a feeling that I may be doing something fundamentally silly here. The issue it seems may be coming from the last set of brackets ( ')))' ) before the 'axis=1' argument.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Create the regular function, not lambda, and apply it to your dataframe.

Comment: Looks like you have an `if` without a matching `else`. I bet that's part of it. Have you considered changing this from a lambda to a regular function? Would be much easier to read.

Comment: What are you trying to do with this function? If you provide some sample input and output it would be easier to determine where your approach is falling short beyond just whatever syntax error has occurred in this massive chained expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nick ODell's comment is correct.   I reformatted your orignal as:

```
master_output['tm_override'] = (
    master_output.apply(lambda row: row['nrec_tm_lb'].astype(str) + '-' + row['nrec_tm_ub'].astype(str) 
    if row['det_tw_fact'].isin([4, 5]) 
    else row['tw2Open'] + dt.timedelta(hours=3).time() 
        if (row['det_tw_fact'].isin([1, 2, 3]) and (~row['tw2Open'].isna()))
        else row['tw1Open'] 
        + dt.timedelta(hours=3).time() 
            if (row['det_tw_fact'].isin([1, 2, 3]) and (~row['tw2Open'].isna())), axis=1)
    )
```

If you look at your last if, there is no matching else.  What you are dealing is I believe is a DataFrame ?  You are trying to assign values to a column, but if you only have if without else, when the if condition is not met, then there is no values to fill the column.

I don't know what values you are going to fill in the else part.  But I've tried filling with ''.  The syntax error goes away.

```
master_output['tm_override'] = (
    master_output.apply(lambda row: row['nrec_tm_lb'].astype(str) + '-' + row['nrec_tm_ub'].astype(str) 
    if row['det_tw_fact'].isin([4, 5]) 
    else row['tw2Open'] + dt.timedelta(hours=3).time() 
        if (row['det_tw_fact'].isin([1, 2, 3]) and (~row['tw2Open'].isna()))
        else row['tw1Open'] 
        + dt.timedelta(hours=3).time() 
            if (row['det_tw_fact'].isin([1, 2, 3]) and (~row['tw2Open'].isna()))
            else '', axis=1)
    )
```

What I get now is a different error because I don't have the DataFrame, but your syntax error is resoved.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-251-72ce849871e0> in <module>
      1 master_output['tm_override'] = (
----> 2     master_output.apply(lambda row: row['nrec_tm_lb'].astype(str) + '-' + row['nrec_tm_ub'].astype(str) 
      3     if row['det_tw_fact'].isin([4, 5])
      4     else row['tw2Open'] + dt.timedelta(hours=3).time()
      5         if (row['det_tw_fact'].isin([1, 2, 3]) and (~row['tw2Open'].isna()))

NameError: name 'master_output' is not defined
```